# remove all text after multiple matched text strings - javascript (or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, filter, split

I have a bunch of dynamically generated paragraphs. I need to catch specific words and if they are part of the paragraph remove all content that follows.

This works for a single parameter, but I can't figure out how to make it work for multiple cases.

```
var endFormatDescription = (FilteredDescription.split('Included in')[0]);
```

In my specific case I need to catch "Include in" "as part of" and "Assigned to"
. Example sentence would be - "This is not a valid item include in the library" and become "This is not a valid item" or "Item not found as part of this library" as "Item not found"

Your time and help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression like this one `/(Included in).*/i` should do the trick.

```
var x = 'This is not a valid item included in the library.';
x.replace(/(Included in).*/i, '');
```

Comment: This one `/( Included in).*/i` will also remove trailing space.
Not that there is a SPACE before **Included in**!

Comment: Here is a regex for your particular case: `/(Included in)|(as part of)|(Assigned to).*/gi`

Comment: Perfect - var new_str = FilteredDescription.split(/(Included in)|(as part of)|(Assigned to).*/gi)[0]; is nice and neat and best of all functioning :D 

Thanks you!